# need to set tabbar image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, image, tabbar

i have selected tab bar based application from templates. in that i need to set the custom image i have tried like given below

```
 UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *view1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *view2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *view3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *view4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];


self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;


self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2,view3,view4, nil];

[self.tabBarController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h.png"]];
```

one more way i have tried

```
    [[_tabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h.png"]];
```

in the second way there is image applied but it's a background.

so i need individually like home button something like that....

how to set this...
thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an set the `images` in `UIViewControllers's` `TabBarItems` like..

```
viewcontroller1.tabBarItems.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image1"];

viewController2.tabBarItems.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image2"];

viewController3.tabBarItems.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image3"];

viewController3.tabBarItems.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
    NSArray *tabs =  tabBarController.viewControllers;
    UIViewController *tab1 = [tabs objectAtIndex:0];
    tab1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clockicon.png"];
    UIViewController *tab2 = [tabs objectAtIndex:1];
    tab2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nearest.png"];
```